# How can selected gallery image show in first activity and another activity?

Tags: android

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    ImageView imgView;
    static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";
    public String[] filePathColon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

                int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, nh, true);
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                final String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

                Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("imageUri", filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops! Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}


public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap ba = this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(ba);
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Delete these lines:

```
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        final String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

Step #2: Replace `intent.putExtra("imageUri", filePath);` with `intent.setData(uri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Step #3: Replace:

```
Bitmap ba = this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
imageView.setImageBitmap(ba);
```

with:

```
Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

Eventually, replace of your bitmap work (the `Bitmap` that you are not using in the first activity, and `setImageURI()` in the second activity) with an image-loading library, such as Picasso, so that you can move all this data processing off the main application thread.

Comment: Thaks but It won't solve. please help me one more...  It not to selected button chage and show same mainActivity gallery image in another Activity.